# How to use dictionary to replace the items in the inner list of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, dictionary

How to use dictionary to replace the items in the inner list of a list?

This works fine

```
import numpy as np
ss_dict = {
        1 : np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0]),
        2 : np.array([0,1,0,0,0,0]),
        3 : np.array([0,0,1,0,0,0]),
        4 : np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0]),
        5 : np.array([0,0,0,0,1,0]),
        6 : np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1]),
    }

l=np.array([1,2,3])
l = np.array([ss_dict[i] for i in l])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

But this got errors `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

```
l=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
l = np.array([ss_dict[i] for i in (j for j in l)])
print(l)
```

I want to output:

```
[
[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
 ]
```

Comment: `for i in (j for j in l)` is just `for i in l`. Are you trying to flatten `l`, i.e. do the equivalent of `for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: I have updated the question, is that okay now? Could you please remove the down-vote if possible? Thank you! @AlexHall

Comment: @lanselibai, sure - see updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. You just need to create a list comprehension within the list comprehension.

```
res = np.array([[ss_dict[j] for j in i] for i in l])
```

Result:

```
[[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 1]]]
```

Comment: I have updated the question now. Basically, I want each number to be replaced by a value in the dictionary.